# MQTT unable to receive message

Tags: mqtt

I have a problem with MQTT.

I have a problem with the Android MQTT.

I have followed this (http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/) demo and was able to run this source code. However, I always receive a message that I am unable to connect to the server. Is there something wrong with the MQTT he has or is there something wrong with my connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don' t know where you run your broker, but in case your MQTT broker is running on your development machine, you can' t connect it via localhost or 127.0.0.1 because "the" localhost is actually your phone or emulator in that case. Instead, you need to give your local IP to connect this MQTT broker. (*ipconfig* for Windows, *ifconfig* for linux command-line)

Answer (score 0):

What is the address of the server you are trying to connect to?

I know that article is fairly old now that the Eclipse Paho client is out, there are some good resources on the MQTT wiki about using it on Android too http://mqtt.org/wiki/doku.php/mqtt_on_the_android_platform

Comment: I tried to connect to my own server (I am running a virtualbox Ubuntu as a server and my phone (not emulator) would have a message from logcat that says unable to connect), but it doesn't seem to connect.

Comment: You could try using the broker hosted at test.mosquitto.org:1883 to help test where the problem lies.